# Protonation of tetrahydrofurfuryl alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

> [image: (Oxolan-2-yl)methanol + H+]

I think the ethereal oxygen in [THFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrofurfuryl_alcohol) gets protonated. Due to greater +I effect, the electron density on it is higher, hence it is more likely to behave as a Lewis base. Consequently, the product formed is **pent-2-en-1,5-diol**:

[image: (Oxolan-2-yl)methanol + H+ to pent-2-en-1,5-diol]

Apparently, this is wrong. What exactly happens here and why my answer is wrong?

Comment: Cleavage of ethers is rather difficult http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14860/cleavage-of-ethers

Comment: Also alcohols are stronger bases than ethers http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46514/why-is-dimethyloxonium-cation-stronger-acid-than-hydronium/46517?s=2|0.0667#46517

Comment: but in this case, there is greater +I effect on the ethereal o than on the alcoholic O. Would that not make the electron density on the ethereal oxygen greater?

Answer (score 7):

The alcohol group of your educt (tetrahydrofurfuryl alcohol) is protonated, and after subsequent loss of water, the resulting primary carbocation can rearrange to a more stable 6-membered ring cation, which is stabilized by resonance. Initial protonation at the ether oxygen is therefore disfavored, as it will not result in the formation of a similarly stable carbocation (with positive charge adjacent to oxygen). After final deprotonation, 2,3-dihydropyran is obtained.

[image]

Comment: The arrow in the third step should be from the C-C bond, not the C-O bond.

Comment: @Lemoine Thanks for catching that, I've corrected the mechanism.