# Write the detailed, stepwise mechanism of this reaction:

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I couldn’t figure out how to turn the five membered ring into 6 membered ring. Pls help

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Protonate -OH, after which water leaves, generating a carbocation, which rearranges, and then an elimination occurs. You should have a look at E1 mechanism.

Comment: I would like to see a solution to this, it looks less than straightforward.

Comment: Looks like an [acid treatment of tetrahydrofurfuryl alcohol leads to 2,3-dihydropyran](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48148/protonation-of-a-compound-having-alcohol-and-ethereal-linkage). That's all good. But I'm not sure how the inclusion of a methyl in the reactant molecule as above leads to the resulting molecule above instead of 6-Methyl-3,4-dihydro-2H-pyran. I'd like to see the solution as well indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the OP having made no effort to answer this, I was intrigued and wanted to see a solution.

The secondary alcohol is protonated by the strong acid, water leaves to generate a secondary cation. With assistance from the ring oxygen, a methylene shift occurs to generate a more stable cation centred on the oxygen. Solvent removes the methine proton to generate the observed dihydropyran product. This only works because of the presence of the oxygen.

[image]

Comment: Please explain how the 'oxygen-centred' cation is more stable?
I have very basic knowlege regarding this and I've learnt that positive charge on less electronegative atom would be much more stable than on a more electronegative one.
Here, oxygen should be the least stable place the positive charge could be put on, right?

Comment: Oxygen has electron pairs that it can donate, enough to make this process viable